# NestJS API Performance

Tags: nestjs

I just created a NestJS App for testing a simple Hello world API endpoint with the following package versions:

```
"dependencies": {
"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^10.1.1",
"@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.2",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
"bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
"dotenv": "^16.3.1",
"mysql2": "^3.6.3",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rxjs": "^7.2.0",
"typeorm": "^0.3.17"
}
```

And my app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Public } from './auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('hello-world')
  @Public()
  helloWorld(): string {
    return 'Hello world!';
  }
}
```

After built it and started as prod environment (npm run start:prod), this /hello-world takes 10-100ms of response time.

But when I test it over AWS EC2 t2.micro, it's takes 500ms - in average. Is it because the distance between AWS region (ea-east-1) and I (south America)? Anyway, avg 500ms for a simple "ping" endpoint its enough, I think.

How else can I measure this?

[image]

What do you guess?
Thanks!